# Whats the name of this matrix or table?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, feature-extraction

i hope you all will be doing fine.

I am having a conceptual problem,I dont know the name of this table and neither i know how can i extract it using scikit-learn.Even, if i knew the correct terminology for this table that would have helped a lot or if someone can tell me, which scikit function to use then it will be awesome.

i have googled it a lot e.g using terms like aggregated table, classification reports but couldn't find this type of table.

[image: This is the table which i know nothing about]

thanks for your time!

happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, but I discovered after searching and discussion with my peers. This is custom matrix used for algorithm comparison on the basis of feature extraction techniques. Thanks [@OmG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3768871/omg) for taking your time to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eli5` package](https://pypi.org/project/eli5/) in python.

> ELI5 is a Python package which helps to debug machine learning classifiers and explain their predictions.

For the specific case, you can use `eli5.show_weights()` function for your classifier. Notice that it works for classifiers in `sklearn` and `sklearn-crfsuit` also.

Comment: Thanks, @OmG for your help, i will try this at once and will let u know

Comment: @DanialShabbir my pleasure.